# What is Difference between using the Scanner class in Java for input and using Strings Args[] with parseint?

Tags: java

What is the difference between the following

```
import java.util.Scanner;
//Creating the scanner
Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the number 1");
int number1=input.nextInt();
```

vs

```
int number1=parseInt(args[0]);
```

Comment: Don't know what the downvotes were for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one reads an integer from standard input.  So you might run it as follows:

```
$ java Foo 
Enter the number 1               <<-- prompt from program.
42
```

The second one gets an integer from the command line.  So you might run it as follows:

```
$ java Foo 42
```

Answer (score 3):

The first is reading from `Standard Input` the second is reading arguments passed in on the command line. The first is interactive input, the second is a one shot type input.

For the second it is much better to use a library like [Java Simple Argument Parser](http://www.martiansoftware.com/jsap/) ( JSAP ). Rather than parsing and converting things yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I will check out the Java Simple Argument Parser